# How to extract timestamp embedded in messages in Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to extract Timestamps embedded with each message and send them as json payload into my database.

I want to get the following three timestamps.

**Event-time:** `The point in time when an event or data record occurred, i.e. was originally created “by the source”.`

**Processing-time:** `The point in time when the event or data record happens to be processed by the stream processing application, i.e. when the record is being consumed.`

**Ingestion-time:** `The point in time when an event or data record is stored in a topic partition by a Kafka broker.`

This is my streams application code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-pipe");
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BROKER_URL + ":9092"); // pass from env localhost:9092 ,BROKER_URL + ":9092"
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

KStream<String, String> source_o365_user_activity = builder.stream("o365_user_activity");

source_o365_user_activity.flatMapValues(new ValueMapper<String, Iterable<String>>() {
    @Override
    public Iterable<String> apply(String value) {
        System.out.println("========> o365_user_activity_by_date Log:     " + value);
        ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            JSONObject send = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject received = new JSONObject(value);

            send.put("current_date", getCurrentDate().toString()); // UTC TIME
            send.put("activity_time", received.get("CreationTime")); // CONSTANTS FINAL STATIC(Topic Names, Cassandra keys)
            send.put("user_id", received.get("UserId"));
            send.put("operation", received.get("Operation"));
            send.put("workload", received.get("Workload"));
            keywords.add(send.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.err.println("Unable to convert to json");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return keywords;
    }
}).to("o365_user_activity_by_date");
```

In the code I am simply getting each record, doing some stream processing on it and sending it to a different topic.

Now with each record I want to send `Event-time`, `Processing-time` and `Ingestion-time` embedded in the payload.

I have looked at the `FailOnInvalidTimestamp` and `WallclockTimestampExtractor` but I am confused on how to use them.

Kindly guide me how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Timestamp` extractor can only give you one timestamp and this timestamp is used for time-based operations like windowed-aggregations or joins. It seems that you don't do any time-based computation thought, thus, from a computation point of view, it does not matter.

Note, that a record has only one metadata timestamp field. This timestamp field can be used to store an event-timestamp that can be set by the producer. As an alternative, you can let the broker overwrite the producer provided timestamp with the broker ingestion time. This is a topic configuration.

To access the record metadata timestamp (independent if it's event-time or ingestion-time), the default timestamp extractor with give you this timestamp. If you want to access it in your application, you need to use Processor API, ie, in your case a `.transform()` instead of a `.flatMap` operator. Your `Transformer` will be initialized with a `context` object that allows you to access the extracted timestamp.

Because a record can only store one metadata timestamp and because you want to use this for broker ingestion time, the upstream producer must put the event-timestamp into the payload directly.

For processing-time, just do a system call as indicated in your code snippet already.

Comment: Can you kindly give an example code snippet. I am getting a hard time understanding it form KStream docs

Comment: Check out example code here: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Comment: which example? I can't find any regarding timestamps

Comment: There are a few classes that use the context, eg, `EventDeduplicationLambdaIntegrationTest` (and a few other tests) or `InventoryService` and `ProbabilisticCounter`